# How to get commit date and time on GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

Actually I have a need to get a timestamp of my commit in GitLab CI.
Alredy have tested the official documentation of GitLab CI Variables here:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables

But there are only commit variables for

- CI_COMMIT_SHA The commit revision for which project is built
- CI_COMMIT_TAG The commit tag name. Present only when building tags.

Is there a way to achieve this? Need to add these values to variables. My prefered way would be to add it to the variables section.

```
job:
  variables:
    COMMIT_TIME: $(git_timestamp)
  script: echo $COMMIT_TIME
```

I'm open to any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes you can get the commit time, like this:

```
job:
  script: 
    - export COMMIT_TIME=$(git show -s --format=%ct $CI_COMMIT_SHA)
    - echo $COMMIT_TIME
```

If you want to have your `COMMIT_TIME` variable in every job use the `before_script` option:

```
before_script:
  - export COMMIT_TIME=$(git show -s --format=%ct $CI_COMMIT_SHA)   

job:
  script: 
    - echo $COMMIT_TIME
```

The `%ct` format gives you unixtimestamp if you want something else, have a look at the PRETTY_FORMATS in [this reference](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-show) on `git show`.

Comment: Thanks, will test it.

Comment: Doesn't using the `before_script` method mean that each job calculates its own date/time?  This could be an issue if the date is important and the pipeline spans midnight.
Oh of course it doesn't because you're looking at the commit.  Nice!

Comment: This saved me a lot of headache. For those that build a container from here and are looking to access the `COMMIT_TIME` variable from inside the container you'll want to use the `before_script:` option as mentioned above before the start of any stage. Then add `COMMIT_TIME: $COMMIT_TIME` to `variables:` (also before the start of any stage). You will now have access to this variable globally in your container.

Comment: This only works if the container running the script happens to have `git` installed.

Answer (score 25):

From GitLab 13.4 you can use a new [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) for this: `CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP`

Example of value: `2022-01-06T01:27:22+01:00`

Comment: Here is an example of value for this variable (so that anyone looking for the date format does not need to run a pipeline to get it): `2022-01-06T01:27:22+01:00`

Answer (score 0):

For **powershell** use $Env:variable_name=value

```
job:
  script: 
    - $Env:COMMIT_TIME=$(git show -s --format=%ct $CI_COMMIT_SHA)
    - WRITE-HOST $Env:COMMIT_TIME
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.3