# Consequences of commit time being in the future

Tags: git, gitlab

I've accidently committed & pushed a change to the remote while my device date time was set to few days in the future(i.e. date is set to 23rd instead of 21st).

I've referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17986403/9479280) which will solve my problem, but advised not to perform it due to the force push.

So my question is will keeping the wrong date and time of a commit adversely effect the Git repo (Local & Remote). I use "Git Lab" as my remote repository provider.

Comment: Generally speaking, no. Some poorly-written tooling that assumes a strictly chronological order might get confused, but in Git all that matters is the `parent` commit references. That said, git was designed around chronologically re-ordered commits anyway -  that's how you `rebase`.

Comment: @Dai according to what I understand you're saying that its not a problem as long as a `rebase` is not performed

Comment: No, I'm saying it's not a problem at all because a `rebase` in git is a very common operation.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is will keeping the wrong date and time of a commit
> adversely effect the Git repo (Local & Remote). I use "Git Lab" as my
> remote repository provider.

The answer is: "it depends". From a git perspective, it does not: the date is recorded as metadata and the commit order is provided based on parent/child relationship. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857467/2125110) for further study.

However, if you [employ CI scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173988/how-to-get-commit-date-and-time-on-gitlab-ci) or care deeply for the actual history of the repository, recording wrong metadata is *bad* in a broad sense. It can be fixed.

On a side note, you may do a lot of stuff with metadata, such as, but not limited to, [creating commits in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339992/how-to-create-a-git-commit-with-date-in-the-past).

> #### Committing
>
> The final creation of a Git commit object is usually done by git-commit-tree, which uses these environment variables as its
> primary source of information, falling back to configuration values
> only if these aren’t present.
>
> `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` is the human-readable name in the “author” field.
>
> `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` is the email for the “author” field.
>
> `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` is the timestamp used for the “author” field.
>
> `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` sets the human name for the “committer” field.
>
> `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` is the email address for the “committer” field.
>
> `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` is used for the timestamp in the “committer”
> field.
>
> `EMAIL` is the fallback email address in case the `user.email`
> configuration value isn’t set. If this isn’t set, Git falls back to
> the system user and host names.
> [source](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables)

This is another very nice reference to understand git internals:

> Let us consider the hashes of these objects for a bit. Let’s say I
> wrote the string `git is awesome!` and created a blob from it. You did
> the same on your system. Would we have the same hash?
>
> The answer is — Yes. Since the blobs consist of the same data, they’ll
> have the same SHA-1 values.
>
> What if I made a tree that references the blob of `git is awesome!`, and
> gave it a specific name and metadata, and you did exactly the same on
> your system. Would we have the same hash?
>
> Again, yes. Since the trees objects are the same, they would have the
> same hash.
>
> What if I created a commit of that tree with the commit message `Hello`,
> and you did the same on your system. Would we have the same hash?
>
> In this case, the answer is — No. Even though our commit objects refer
> to the same tree, they have different commit details — time, committer
> etc.
> [source](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-internals-objects-branches-create-repo/)

Answer (score 1):

> but advised not to perform it due to the force push.

Any rebase would necessitate a force push for the rebased branch to be published.

But that is only an issue is this is done on a public branch where multiple collaborators are working on.

If it is your own working/topic branch, you can rebase/force push as many times as you want.
This is actually done [before a pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51405734/6309), to ensure an easy merge by the maintainer (or the maintainer can [trigger the rebase themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39707453/6309)).